# Accessing files within child directories

Tags: c#

I am trying to access the files in the images directory that lies within another directory but when I run my code it doesn't print out anything:

```
string path = @"C:\Path";
DirectoryInfo DFolder = new DirectoryInfo(path);
Collection cDetails = new Collection(DFolder);
string DFPath = DFolder.Name;

DirectoryInfo imDetails = new DirectoryInfo(imPath);

// Get Desired Directories    
List<string> directoryFilter = new List<string> {"images", "videos", "RAW"};

List<DirectoryInfo> directoryList = DFolder
    .GetDirectories("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Where(x => directoryFilter.Contains(x.Name.ToLower()))
    .ToList();

string dpath = directoryList.ToString();

foreach (DirectoryInfo record in directoryList)
{
    foreach (FileInfo file in record.GetFiles(@"*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(file); //It compiles but doesn't print anything on the console
    }
}
```

Comment: SO is a terrible debugger! You need to debug or even just use print debugging to understand code you have written. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: If you're going to do a lower-case comparison on the directory names, you might want to change `"RAW"` to `"raw"`...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 foreach (FileInfo file in record.GetFiles(@"*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
{
    Console.WriteLine(file); //It compiles but doesn't print anything on the console
}
```

`SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly` will only search files in `C://Path/images` but not its subfolders.

a possible fix for this is to simply change your **2nd foreach loop** to look like this:

```
foreach (FileInfo file in record.GetFiles(@"*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    Console.WriteLine(file); //It compiles but doesn't print anything on the console
}
```

**Edit:**

Using `SearchOption.AllDirectories` as parameter is supposed to catch all cases of subfolders within your subfolder e.g. something like `C://images//dir//somefile.txt` instead of only taking the files within the topdirectory(in this case `C://images`). Which is(as i understood your question) exactly the kind of behaviour you were looking for.
Full code:

```
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
  { 
    // Directory Info
    string path = @"C:\Path";
    DirectoryInfo DFolder = new DirectoryInfo(path);
    string DFPath = DFolder.Name;


    // Get Desired Directories

    List<string> directoryFilter = new List<string> { "images", "videos", "raw" };

    List<DirectoryInfo> directoryList = DFolder.GetDirectories("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(x => directoryFilter.Contains(x.Name.ToLower())).ToList(); 

    string dpath = directoryList.ToString();

    foreach (DirectoryInfo record in directoryList)
    {

        foreach (FileInfo file in record.GetFiles(@"*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)) //searches directory record and its subdirectories
        {
            Console.WriteLine(file); 
        }

    }
}
```

**Final Edit:** Sample output given the following structure:

```
C://Path//images//images.somefile.txt
C://Path//images//temp//images.temp.somefile.txt
C://Path//raw//raw.somefile.txt
C://Path//vidoes//videos.somefile.txt
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this will show all the files within the main Directory. There are multiple directories within and I just want to retrieve files from one specific subdirectory.

Comment: I'm not sure this solves anything...`record` in this case represents all sub-directories under `path` (since we're inside a loop where `record` gets assigned to the result of `directoryList`, which *does* have the `SearchOption.AllDirectories` flag set.

Comment: @RufusL's response already said everything i wanted to say. Maybe i could've been a bit clearer in my initial statement. I just didn't think it was necessary to provide "more" detail, since the code was easy enough to understand. Sorry for the hiccup.

Comment: I'm not at a computer, but won't your code output the same file numerous times? You're using `SearchOption.AllDirectories` on both the inner AND outer loops.

Comment: `DFolder.**GetDirectories**("*",SearchOption.AllDirectories)` and `record.**GetFiles**(@"*", SearchOption.AllDirectories`) are not the same thing. The first loop finds occurences of directory names in any given directory.The second loop actually searches for files within those found directories. Hope that helps to make it a bit clearer.

Comment: Sure, I understand that. But the point is that in the outer loop you're already searching through all directories. So the inner loop should only output files for the current directory. Otherwise, if you have a structure like: `"C:\Path\images\raw"`, all the files in the `raw` folder will be output twice - once when searching for all files in all directories under `"C:\Path\images"`, and again when it searching for all files in all directories under `"C:\Path\images\raw"`

Comment: It doesn't. As you can see given the sample output. The linq statement only adds the directories that contain specific files in the first place and then you loop through those same directories.  It does not, however list the files themselves. Could this code be written far more eloquent & in turn easier to read/be less redundant? Most definitely. But i only changed the code OP provided in the first place. Hope that clears things up.

Answer (score 0):

Note: This isn't really an answer, so I'll delete it shortly, but wanted to give some sample code to test with in case it helps.

Your code works fine for me, so it seems that the problem is that either the directories don't exist, or they don't contain any files.

Here's a test program you can run which creates a bunch of directories under `c:\temp`, some of which have the names we care about. The names we care about are also found at different levels of depth in the path, yet they are all discovered:

```
static void CreateTestPathsAndFiles()
{
    // Paths to create for testing. We will put a file in each directory below,
    // but our search code should only print the file paths of those files that
    // are directly contained in one of our specially-named folders
    var testPaths = new List<string>
    {
        @"c:\temp\dummy1",
        @"c:\temp\dummy1\raw",         // This should print
        @"c:\temp\dummy2",
        @"c:\temp\dummy2\extra",
        @"c:\temp\dummy3",
        @"c:\temp\dummy3\dummy31",
        @"c:\temp\dummy3\dummy32\raw", // This should print
        @"c:\temp\extra",
        @"c:\temp\images",             // This should print
        @"c:\temp\notUsed",
        @"c:\temp\notUsed\videos",     // This should print
        @"c:\temp\raw",                // This should print
        @"c:\temp\videos\dummy1",
    };

    // Just something to make a unique file name
    int fileId = 0;

    // for testing, ensure that the directories exist and contain some files
    foreach(var testPath in testPaths)
    {
        // Create the directory
        Directory.CreateDirectory(testPath);

        // Add a file to it
        File.CreateText(Path.Combine(testPath, $"TempFile{fileId}.txt"))
            .Write($"Dummy text in file {fileId}");

        // Increment our file counter
        fileId++;
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Create our paths and files for testing
    CreateTestPathsAndFiles();

    // Now set our root directory, search for all folders matching our 
    // special folder names, and print out the files contained in them
    var path = @"C:\Temp";
    var directoryFilter = new List<string> {"images", "videos", "raw"};

    // Get ALL sub-directories under 'path' whose name is in directoryFilter
    var subDirectories = new DirectoryInfo(path)
        .GetDirectories("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        .Where(x => directoryFilter.Contains(x.Name.ToLower()));

    foreach (DirectoryInfo subDir in subDirectories)
    {
        foreach (FileInfo file in subDir.GetFiles(@"*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
        {
            // We're using the FullName so we see the whole file path in the output
            Console.WriteLine(file.FullName);
        }
    }

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

**Output**

Note that the 5 files we expected to find are listed, but no others:

[image]